# How to transform the action Dependent Feature (ADF) from categorical to continuos/discrete?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am following the Vowpalwabbit [tutorial](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/cb_simulation.html)  on contextual MABs using cb_explore_adf and I was wondering how to transform the actions namespace feature into numeric so it could generialize better for a new arm.

In this tutorial they present click-through rate (CTR) problem where the actions are the kind of articles to show:

```
shared |User user=Tom time_of_day=morning
|Action article=politics
|Action article=sports
|Action article=music
|Action article=food
```

As we cansse see, the article feature in the namespace Action is set to be a categorical value (politics, food, etc ...)

Is it possible to transform it into numeric?  Lets say that in my problem I am showing constumers a price:

```
shared |User user=Tom time_of_day=morning
|Action price=2.99
|Action price=10.99
```

if I want to test a new price, let's say $6.99... would the previus training bring some information?

What I understand, VowpalWabbit uses ":" for numeric features...is that true?

```
shared |User user=Tom time_of_day=morning
|Action price:2.99
|Action price:10.99
```

I tried this out, but it didn't work... in fact it made the model unable to covnerge.

What did I miss?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using numeric features is correct.
Are you still trying to play with the simulator that is provided in tutorial?
If so, have you changed rewarding logic (get_cost function) - right now it is assigning rewards based on person and time_of_day. If you want to play with new features, you would probably need to change logic there to make rewards correlated with your new feature.